# Flexibly edit json values in C#

Tags: c#, json

I've been trying to insert values from one json file into another. These structures have mostly been decided on, so I want to try and make them work as they are.
The problem i've been running into is that the provided paths may not always have the same depth and thus the coded used to insert values into that provided path needs to be flexible enough to deal with that.

These are the json files:

this json holds values, the paths to where those values should be placed in the other json file and when applicable, the index.

```json
[ 
    {
      "path": "x_axis.data",
      "value": "['','2005','2010','2015','2021','2026']",
      "index": null
    },
    {
      "path": "series.data",
      "value": "[77.0,70.0,74.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]",
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "path": "series.data",
      "value": "[0.0,0.0,0.0,99.0,100.0,100.0]",
      "index": 1
    }
 ]
```

This json is a template structure that will be reused. it' based on the Echarts documentation, since we use that library to show charts.

```json
{
  "tooltip": {
    "trigger": "axis",
    "axisPointer": {
      "type": "shadow"
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "data": [ "One", "Two" ]
  },
  "grid": {
    "left": "3%",
    "right": "4%",
    "bottom": "3%",
    "containLabel": true
  },
  "xAxis": [
    {
      "type": "category",
      "data": []
    }
  ],
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "type": "value"
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "One%",
      "type": "bar",
      "stack": "Stack 1",
      "emphasis": {
        "focus": "series"
      },
      "itemStyle": {
        "color": "blue"
      },
      "data": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Two%",
      "type": "bar",
      "stack": "Stack 1",
      "emphasis": {
        "focus": "series"
      },
      "itemStyle": {
        "color": "red"
      },
      "data": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently my method converts the path into a string array with text formatting that matches the names in the template json. I am however unsure how to use it or whether it was the right choice.
Here is my code:

```cs
 public static string GenerateChart(string templateString, string replacementValuesString)
        {
            string result = "";

            dynamic templateJson = JObject.Parse(templateString);
            dynamic replacementJson = JArray.Parse(replacementValuesString);

            foreach (var item in replacementJson)
            {
                string[] pathArr = CreatePathArray(item);

                //check for index
                if (item.index != null)
                {   
                    //TODO: Implement code that handles the index
                    templateJson.path = item.value;

                }
                else
                {
                    templateJson.path = item.value;
                }

            }

            result = templateJson.ToString();

            return result;
        }
```

I used Newtonsoft to parse the json. My team decided against using models to deserialise the Json because they wanted to be able to only edit the json files for maintenance of the program.

My question to anyone willing to help is how would you go about solving this problem?
If I've failed to explain bits properly please let me know so I can clarify.

Thank you for your help!

Edit 1: I forgot to mention how the path is split into the array. It's split at the period, so "x_axis.data" becomes "["xAxis", "data"]".

**Thanks to E. Shcherbo for helping me find a solution**
I ended up modifying the code he suggested to fit my project as a few minor things were causing issues. Here's the code I ended up using and will now continue to polish:

```cs
var replacementJson = JArray.Parse(replacementValuesString);
            JToken templateJson = JObject.Parse(templateString);

            foreach (var item in replacementJson)
            {
                string[] pathArr = CreatePathArray(item);

                //The method using ^1 provided by E. Shcherbo didn't work for me here. 
                //I'm guessing it's because I'm working in an old version of dotnetframework.
                var valuePropName = pathArr[pathArr.Length - 1];
                
                //Using this loop to "dive deeply" into the template json as E. put it, we find the correct path and then modify it.
                for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    var pathKey = pathArr[i];
                    templateJson = templateJson[pathKey];

                    if (templateJson == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Template path given is invalid.");
                        break;
                    }

                }

                // if my item contains a value for index, it will be used. Otherwise it's safe to assume we're not dealing with an array.
                if (item["index"] != null)
                {
                    UpdateValueInTemplate(templateJson, item["index"], valuePropName, item["value"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateValueInTemplate(templateJson, valuePropName, item["value"]);
                }

                templateJson = templateJson.Root;

            }
```

Comment: `My team decided against using models to deserialise the Json because they wanted to be able to only edit the json files for maintenance of the program` you can still edit the data and serialize it, just a thought.

Comment: @zaggler
how would we then go about avoiding having to edit the model class in case we want to modify other properties in the template?

Comment: Giving your approach with an array, you can just iterate through the array and go deeply and deeply in the `templateJson` with each item of your path. When you reach the last item in your path array you know this is the property of `templateJson` to update

Comment: @E.Shcherbo
So I would use something like an if statement to check if the current layer of the template json matches the string in the path array of that iteration?

Comment: @DylanAgriSyst this is kind of validation, if your path can be wrong (meaning that it has property which is missing in your template) of course you should do something with it. You can also employ `SelectToken` function to which you can simply pass all your path and get back an array. After this you can just add items to the array

Comment: Something like this `var dataArray = templateJson.SelectToken(yourPath);` then for each `item.Value` just call `dataArray.Add`. Note that `yourPath` should be path with dots as it's written in your `replacementJson`

Comment: @E.Shcherbo
SelectToken returns the value at the given path. I want to modify the value at the path. Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, this is right, but as far as I understand your value is always an array, so that you get a **reference** to a `JArray` object which you can modify. If your value can be a value type, then you can use `SelectToken` just without the last property in the path and then modify with `token[value] = newValue`

Comment: Let me sum this up in the answer, so you can see

Comment: @E.Shcherbo Ah fair enough. That makes sense. I'm eager to see your answer, as it is a possibility that the value is a primitive type and not an array. That's just the case in my example and I should have clarified. 
Thank you in advance for your help so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you probably don't need `dynamic` type here, because you know types of your objects at compile time `JObject, JArray, JToken`, so this is much safer to use them (you can go with `var`).

I'll describe two approaches I see here (both of them reuse the `UpdateValueInTemplate` method).

**Note: be careful with different edge cases which might be possible depending on what you can and can't assume about your data.**

Giving your approach with an array which represents the path, you can just iterate through the array and go deeply and deeply in your `templateJson`. Something like this

```
JToken templateJson = JObject.Parse(templateString);
var valuePropName = pathArr[^1]; // ^1 means first from the end

for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length - 1; i++)
{
   var pathKey = pathArr[i];
   templateJson = templateJson[pathKey];

   if (templateJson is null)
      // The path is wrong. Do whatever validation is expected
}

UpdateValueInTemplate(templateJson, valuePropName, item["value"]);
```

You can also pass your path from `replacementJson` (without the last property to get an object where the last property is rather than value of the property) into the `SelectToken` method. Something like this:

```
var path = item["path"].ToString();
var lastPathSplitter = item.Path.LastIndexOf('.');
var pathWithoutLastProperty = path.Substring(0, lastPathSplitter);
var valPropName = item.Path.Substring(lastPathSplitter + 1);

var jsonToUpdate = templateJson.SelectToken(pathWithoutLastProperty);

if (jsonToUpdate is null)
   // The path is wrong. Do whatever validation is expected

UpdateValueInTemplate(jsonToUpdate, valPropName, item["value"]);
```

Then the `UpdateValueInTemplate` method can look like this:

```
void UpdateValueInTemplate(JToken tokenToUpdate, string valPropName, JToken value) {
   tokenToUpdate[valPropName] = value;
}
```

You can also reduce manipulations with your path if you pass the entire path to the `SelectToken` and then will use `yourToken.Parent.Parent[valPropName] = value` to update the json.

**UPDATE**

I didn't notice that you also want to handle cases where the first property of the path can point to the array. So when this is the case it can be handled like this:

```
JToken templateJson = JObject.Parse(templateString);
var valuePropName = pathArr[^1]; // ^1 means first from the end

for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length - 1; i++)
{
   var pathKey = pathArr[i];
   templateJson = templateJson[pathKey];

   if (templateJson is null)
   {
      // The path is wrong. Do whatever validation is expected
   }
   else if (templateJson.Type == JTokenType.Array)
   {
       int index = item["index"].ToObject<int>(); // you may want to validate the index presence and format
       templateJson = templateJson[index];
   }
}
```

For approach with `SelectToken` you can either change your replacement json to match the format `SelectToken` understands or create a new path based on the index **when it's not null**:

```
var firstPropSplitter = path.IndexOf('.');

var firstProperty = path.Substring(0, firstPropSplitter);
var restPath = path.Substring(firstPropSplitter + 1);

var index = item["index"];
var newPath = $"{firstProperty}[{index}].{restPath}";
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this might just be able to work. 
I am however running into the problem that the JToken provided by item.Value doesn't return the are that is actually it's value. Rather it's the array between {} for some reason.

This is after changing item.Value to item["value"] since I changed replacementJson's type to var instead of dynamic. 
Leaving it as dynamic caused item.Value to be seen as a "method group"
thoughts?

Comment: Sorry didn't get the problem, are there errors after you start using `item["value"]` ?

Comment: yes. In this case tokenToUpdate[valPropName] is  "data", which is a JArray. As such to set the value I need item[value] to actually be an array when given as parameter. but it seems it isn't and I don't understand why. Checking the values during debugging shows that it's a proper array before being passed as parameter into UpdateValueInTemplate()

Comment: Could you please show the error (compile time or runtime) you get?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Set JArray values with invalid key value: "data". Int32 array index expected.'
     This is in the the UpdateValueInTemplate method.

Comment: It seems like your `tokenToUpdate` is your `data` array, but should be the object in which this array is. Which approach do you use to go through the path? Have you ensured that you when you're going through the path you skip the last property?

Comment: Oh this is probably due to your the last case where the path can include arrays with indices. Approaches I suggested don't handle this, because I missed this from your question, sorry.

Comment: `tokenToUpdate` is the object above `data`. It's `value` that' formatted wrong. Somehow being `{['','2005','2010','2015','2021','2026','2031','2036','2041','2046','2051','21.03.04','21,03,04','21.03.0','03.09.05','21.09.05','03.','030905','21.14.02','21.19.03','21-19-03','21.23.04']}` 
 instead of `['','2005','2010','2015','2021','2026','2031','2036','2041','2046','2051','21.03.04','21,03,04','21.03.0','03.09.05','21.09.05','03.','030905','21.14.02','21.19.03','21-19-03','21.23.04']`

I think I may still be able to use your code tho, so Thank you

Comment: I think you see the error just because you can have paths that starts with arrays like in your example. You have `series` array and index `0`. Now the code doesn't handle this and the path `series.data` will return `series` array to you. Then you try set the `data` property of the array like this `tokenToUpdate["data"]`, but this is wrong because `tokenToUpdate` is a `series` array and array expects integers as indicies, not strings